# Spring Boot: How do I create properties that paramterize multiple beans of the same type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to consume a third-party API that segments its host URL per resource.

So for my third-party, they have URLs that are templated like this:

```
https://<high-level-resource-id-foo>.example.com/<path-to-lower-resource-bar>
```

and my client code is structured to consume a host URL in its constructor and then perform work on the low level resources.

```
// Bean definition
@Bean
public FooExampleClient fooExampleClient(@Value("${foo-client.host}" String host) {
    return new FooExampleClient(host);
}

// Consumed later as a dependency elsewhere.
public void elsewhere(int barId) {
    this.fooExampleClient.doWork(barId);
}
```

Which fits into most spring properties structures fairly easily:

```ini
foo-client.host=https://123.example.com
```

My requirements, I've found much later, now require my application to work on multiple high-level resources in this third-party.

Is there a clean or relatively simply way to structure configuration classes and properties so that I can define multiple clients easily and relatively dynamically without a lot of specifically hard-coded references per needed client?

I imagine the properties to look something like this:

```ini
foo-client.foo-a.url=https://foo-a.example.com
foo-client.foo-b.url=https://foo-b.example.com
// ...
foo-client.foo-zzz.url=https://foo-zzz.example.com
```

but I don't know how I'd dynamically "look up" a client for `foo-a` or `foo-b` without hard-coding references to either. Can dynamically iterate over each client so I can drive the application by my configuration and add/delete clients by updating the properties?